Endless processing for a new Speech Studio custom keyword model
I'm very new to Azure and Speech Studio. Anyway I followed the documentation to create a new custom keyword (model type "basic"). According the documentation, it would require "up to 30 minutes for the model to be generated". Yesterday 7 AM I created a new keyword model, but this afternoon it was still in the "processing" status.... more than 30 hours of processing time!
I tried with the creation of new custom keyword, but the result is always the same: endless "processing".
Question(s): according your experience which is the typical time required for a keyword basic model to be created? Are there known aspects to take in charge when creating custom keywords?
PS: not sure this is the correct place is SO where to ask
UPDATE: The keyword basic model was created: it took around 16 hours of processing time. I leave open the question because it could be interesting to hear for other people experience.

How did you get yours to complete? I've been waiting for a Basic model for 48 hours now.

Sincerely I don't know: at one point.... it completed. It seems the the timing is unpredictable. Probably it can also depend on the region you are working on, and the resource availability of that region at the time of processing. Anyway the official documentation is definitely to be corrected.
